# React Native : manipulate dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an application to calculate routine check dates on machines. To calculate those i need 3 initial dates. To get those, i have :

```
<DatePicker
    date={this.state.dateLast}
    mode="date"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    minDate="01-01-1950"
    maxDate="01-01-2050"
    androidMode="spinner"
    showIcon={false}
    onDateChange={(dateLast) => { this.setState({ dateLast: dateLast }); }}
/>
```

Then, i would like to print them in an alert (if that's possible). For now, i have a button :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Calculer</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and his function :

```
_onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('Resultats', "what the f*ck am i going to do")
}
```

My question is : Can i manipulate dates, like, add a year, or substract 3 months, or whatever in that register. I would also like to know if i can indeed print my dates in an 'alert' (a popup window).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can print a date inside Alert like this.

```
Alert.alert("Date is::-",this.state.dateLast)
```

if this don't work then use this ::-

```
Alert.alert("Date is::-",JSON.stringify(this.state.dateLast));
```

OR

```
Alert.alert("Date is::-",this.state.dateLast.toString())
```

Hope this will work.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help !

I am getting a "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dateLast')" I don't really know where it comes from, i'm knid of a noob :/ 
Would you know ? :)